# how to invoke adapters hybrid application MobileFirst Platform 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i have some error

> Caused by:  FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project EMoney]InquiryAdapters/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project EMoney]
>   Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to rss.cnn.com:80 [rss.cnn.com/74.125.200.121] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>
> FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project EMoney]org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to rss.cnn.com:80 [rss.cnn.com/74.125.200.121] failed: Connection timed out: connectjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to rss.cnn.com:80 [rss.cnn.com/74.125.200.121] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to rss.cnn.com:80 [rss.cnn.com/74.125.200.121] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

**inquiryAdapters.xml**

```
<wl:adapter name="InquiryAdapters"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

<displayName>InquiryAdapters</displayName>
<description>InquiryAdapters</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getStories"/>

<procedure name="getStoriesFiltered"/>

<procedure name="getFeedsFiltered"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

**inquiryAdapters.impl**

```
function getStories(interest) {
path = getPath(interest);

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : path
};
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);}


function getStoriesFiltered(interest) {
path = getPath(interest);

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : path,
    transformation : {
        type : 'xslFile',
        xslFile : 'filtered.xsl'
    }
};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);}


function getFeedsFiltered() {

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : "rss.xml",
    transformation : {
        type : 'xslFile',
        xslFile : 'filtered.xsl'
    }
};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);}


function getPath(interest) {
if (interest == undefined || interest == '') {
    interest = '';
}else {
    interest = '_' + interest;
}
return 'rss/edition' + interest + '.rss';}
```

when i want to invoke the adapters (http adapters).

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking the adapter? What does `www.w3schools.com` has to do with it?

Comment: i do like a tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/

Comment: @user3879559, you did not reply to the question - what did you change in your code that the error mentions w3schools? That error cannot show up out of nowhere. Edit the question with the actual code you are using.

Comment: Describe the steps you have followed. How did you try invoking. What did you change in your applicative/adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the next steps yet you get a "Connection timed out" error, you likely have a network issue unrelated to MobileFirst Platform 6.3: check for any firewalls that prevent your connection to arrive to CNN.com

1. Created a new project
2. Create a new HTTP adapter
3. Right-click on adapter folder > Deploy MobileFirst Adapter
4. Right-click on adapter folder > Call  MobileFirst Adapter

Now a browser window with the response should've opened.

Comment: one more sir, i have webservice and i follow this step " https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/  " when i want to preview my apps i get "connection time out" right now because firewall was on 
then when firewall was off can to preview that but i had error "unable to get property changepage of undefined or null reference" in javascript do you know what it is?